# Python: format string as table in non-monospace font

Tags: python, format, slack, slack-api, monospace

I'm working on a Slack Webhooks integration with Slack [Slash commands](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands). My script flow is as following:

1. Getting a slash command request from a Slack.
2. Processing the data (in a form of dict or Pandas DataFrame)
3. Posting back to the channel using the Slack webhook.

My response is a set of key:value records or two columns dataframe. I want to print them nicely into Slack, however I ran into a formatting problem.

1. Using Slack back-ticks to make a code block with monospace font would not work, because I might have very large records, and Slack trims the string after 8000 characters.
2. Printing the lines without monospace, as a plain text, results in an ugly columns with different width in each row.

I tried all sorts of formatting tricks, but could not find a good way to format a response using the Slack API as two very long columns. I guess I am looking for a good library that would format a string for me given the font being used.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slack messages are not really designed to handle large sets of structured data sets. In my personal opinion the best option would be to provide a link to a webpage for showing that data.

However,if you want to show the data within Slack I would recommend to upload it as plain text file. Those can be much larger than 8.000 chars and they can be displayed with a monospaced font, which would allow you to format them properly.

Check out [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) with `filetype` set to `text` to upload and share a file in a channel.

Comment: That was my conclusion after trying various formatting ways. Thought I might be missing something, but it seems like files.upload() is the way to go.